# Joomla plugins get regularly disabled

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I've got a Joomla 1.5.17 web site, with the following components installed:

- JCE 1.5.7
- Jcomments 2.1
- JoomFish 2.0.4
- JoomlaPack
- Kunena Forum 1.5.11
- Xmap

For some unknown (to me) reason, some of the plugins get regularly disabled. I'm not doing it, it just keeps on happening every few weeks. When I notice it, I just go to the backend and re-enable them.

The JoomFish plugin call Jfdatabase is particularly concerned by this weird behavior. Other plugins seem to be randomly disabled too, but this is always a part of the disabled ones.

I know the site is outdated, but I don't have the time right now to update it. I'd just like for it to keep on running smoothly for a few months, without having to fix it up every other week.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26 which is the latest of the 1.5 series. You're 9 versions behind!! Could be that someone is hacking your site, no idea, but I wouldn't be surprised seing as you're on an ancient version of Joomla

Comment: I was hopping someone could maybe detect some incompatibility between certain plugins. I want to avoid udpdates, as mentioned in the OP. However, udating to the last minor version of Joomla shouldn't take too much time, you're right. But then, I should also update the plugins: they may contain security flaws, too.

Comment: As @Lodder says, the first step in trying to solve this should be to update Joomla and all the third party extensions to the latest available versions. Older versions of JCE Editor, Kunena and Xmap have known security vulnerabilities and from memory, I think Joomlapack also had a security issue. There is a reasonable chance the website has already been compromised. I'd be very tempted to do a security audit using Phil Taylor's tool at myJoomla.org (your first audit is free).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not magic that is going to make database values change without running some code. Something is running code. It sounds like you may have a compromised site.  Are you sure those plugins are working? Because there was one release in the 1.5 series that automatically disabled plugins that failed; in addition to the security audit I'd do an audit of all those plugins and make sure you are on the current releases.

Comment: You might be onto something, using your answer I could find this page: http://docs.joomla.org/Why_are_my_plugins_automatically_disabling. I'm going to give it a try (disable the auto-disable thing), and see if it changes anything. If it works, I'll just let it like this until I update the site next year. I'll post the result of this test here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try checking your file permissions. Folders should be set to 0755 and files should be 0644.

The free version of Akeeba Admin Tools can help check and reset file file permissions throughout your website.

See https://www.akeebabackup.com/compatibility.html for the appropriate version of Admin Tools for your version of Joomla and PHP version.